# SVG graphics fully black when opening it as SVG Marker in QGIS

Tags: qgis-2, import, markers, svg

I have an SVG graphic that should be placed in certain locations on my map in QGIS 2.18.

[image: Original_SVG_Marker]

It is accessible via JSFiddle: [SVG_Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zsxmjao9/)

I can open it through Adobe Photoshop, Inkscape, Chrome, it even obeys Internet Explorer.

As for me, everything looks okay when I check my SVG element through Notepad++.

However, when I modify the point symbology through `Layer Properties > Style > Single Symbol > SVG Marker` I am getting a fully black icon, see the image below.

Any suggestions on how can I overcome this issue?

[image: SVG_Result_in_QGIS]

Comment: I would suggest linking the SVG or quoting the SVG's markup in the question. There is no way to know what's wrong with it as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case deleting `<defs>` and `</defs>` (but not it's content) from the SVG graphics for instance with Notepad++ solved my issue. See the image below.

```
<defs> #delete this tag
<style>
  .cls-1{fill:url(#Unbenannter_Verlauf_20);}
  .cls-2{fill:#80ba27;}
</style>

<linearGradient id="Unbenannter_Verlauf_20" x1="25.35" y1="50" x2="25.35" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#004a99"/>
  <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#024d99"/>
  <stop offset="0.63" stop-color="#075699"/>
  <stop offset="0.86" stop-color="#106699"/>
  <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#136b99"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs> #delete this tag
```

[image: Result_Example]

---

**References:**

- [SVG element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs)
- [SVG defs Elements](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/defs-element.html)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar case after creating a svg via Notepad++ and was able to solve it by copying header-data from a different, working svg-file until the new file worked. Rather crude solution, but it works.

Comment: Feel free to do so, if you found a more fitting solution.